# Why is it recommended to create your lists in host web?

Tags: 2013

I went through many forums and blogs, all stating that you should store your data in host web.

One of main reason they stated is because you can set permissions on host web list items which is not possible with app web.

Not many apps in store are only using app web for storing data. What is the best practice ?

Answer (score 2):

The main reason for me would be that the data is more persistant in the host web, it will stay there even if you reinstall your app or delete your app (if you want it to).

If stored in the app web it will be deleted on updates and uninstallation of the app.

Comment: That's a valid point, but what if Microsoft in future says- you can manage permissions in app web too and not allowed to touch host web then ?

Comment: Microsoft has already turned and recommend themself to store files in the host web, not the app web. So I do not see why that should be a valid argument?

Comment: seems like i missed the news then - reference would satisfy me well

Answer (score 1):

It depends, some Apps would have their files & items in the App web as the App would be a stand alone App, and it won't interact that much with the host web. Other Apps would need the host web to reference files provided by the App, so they tend to store these files & create items inside the host web.